# iOS accessory SDK - 3.5mm jack control

Tags: ios, sdk, external, accessory, jack

I want to create a project which will interact with the iPhone/iPad via the 3.5mm jack. There are a bunch of these accessories on kickstarter.com. Although, I could't find any SDK that will provide me the possibility to get data from jack input.

I have seen that some people at progical.com have a sort of SDK that can manage this kind of connection but they haven't answered me yet (I applied for their SDK few months ago). Is there any alternative for that? I want to make this project in order to get my degree so the Apple MFI won't apply.

The project will consist in a bunch of sensors that will send data to my app using 3.5 audio jack. Using my app, I will process the received data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5" Jack connector is originally supposed to send and receive audio data. It means that if a connection is plugged in, the OS will automatically redirect all audio signals to it (with a few exceptions). Thus, you can access the data using the built-in audio processing APIs of iOS, for example CoreAudio and audio queues.

As an example, you can generate and receive signals of different frequencies, which can be used to control and get information from external devices (you'll need some kind of electrical engineering for this to work, though - filtering, separating control frequencies, etc.).

Comment: I was wondering how to get these things working...maybe a tutorial online or some companies that have developed a SDK..check progical.com to see what I am looking for, but those guys won't answer to my application.

Comment: @stonycis Some math and s bit of electronics, nothing more (have a look at Fourier transforms, how PLLs work, you'll see it's similar). For example, turning on and off an LED using two sine waves of different frequencies is a good starting point.